# LaTeX in plot titles using a loop

Tags: r, plot, latex

I just learned how to insert (a limited number of) LaTeX expressions into my plot titles with
`expression(<LaTeX code>)`. How can I generate plots containing LaTeX in their titles using a *loop*? For example, say I have:

```
par(mfrow = c(2,2))

x <- seq(1,10,0.1)
y <- sin(x)

plot(x, y, main = expression(sigma[1]))
plot(x, y, main = expression(sigma[2]))
```

This produces the desired output:
[image]

How can I achieve the same output, but by replacing the last two lines with a loop? I tried

```
par(mfrow = c(2,2))
for (i in 1:2){
    plot(x, y, main = expression(sigma[i]))
}
```

but the `i` was not interpreted as a variable:
[image]

Any solutions for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `bquote` instead of `expression`. This allows partial unquoting, meaning you can substitute the *value* of *i* inside the expression by wrapping it like this: `.(i)`

```r
par(mfrow = c(2,2))

x <- seq(1,10,0.1)
y <- sin(x)

for(i in 1:4) plot(x, y, main = bquote(paste("My plot for ", sigma[.(i)], " :")))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! I have a follow-up question: Suppose I want the titles to contain some regular text as well which is fixed across all plots, e.g. "My plot for $\sigma = 1$",  "My plot for $\sigma = 2$", "My plot for $\sigma = 3$", etc...  How should I modify your code to achieve this?

Comment: I tried `plot(x, y, main = paste0("My plot for ", bquote(expression(sigma)), " = ", toString(i)))`, but the sigma that showed up was not in TeX form, and it also created the title twice for each plot.

Comment: @Leonidas see my update - you can use `paste`

Answer (score 4):

```
par(mfrow = c(2,2))
loop.vector <- 1:2

for (i in loop.vector) {
  x <- seq(1,10,0.1)
  y <- sin(x)
  plot(x, y, main = bquote(sigma[.(i)]))
}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes you are right. I think you were faster. Should i delete?

Answer (score 3):

Another option is `substitute`

```
for (i in 1:2){
     plot(x, y, main = substitute(paste("My plot for ", sigma[i]), list(i = i)))
 }
```

-output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For your reference, there is also `tikzDevice`, which actually generates `.tex`:

```r
sigma <- 2^(1:4)
x <- seq(0, 2 * pi, 0.01 * pi)

tikzDevice::tikz("sine.tex", standAlone = TRUE)
par(mfrow = c(2L, 2L))
for (i in seq_along(sigma)) {
    y <- sin(sigma[i] * x)
    plot(x, y, type = "o", xlab = "$x$", ylab = "$y$", 
         main = sprintf("$y = \\sin(\\sigma_{%d} x)$", i))
}
dev.off()
tools::texi2dvi("sine.tex", pdf = TRUE)
system(paste(getOption("pdfviewer"), "sine.pdf"))
```

[image]